# Etymological history of "northmost" and "northernmost"

Tags: etymology

How did it happen that we have both *northmost* and *northernmost*? Was there a typo or mistake in a letter once, or was it a conscious decision to change the original word, or add a synonym to that word?

Which word came first? Has one of the words been regarded as incorrect in the past?

Comment: [A quick Google Books NGram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=northmost%2C+northernmost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) finds that 'northernmost' is by far more common than 'northmost', so an explicit etymology of the latter probably is not going to come up with much. '-most' is a productive but not common suffix, so it may not be explicitly given with 'northern' either.

Comment: The other way to express the idea is 'the most northerly' but the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=northmost%2Cnorthernmost%2C+most+northerly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnorthmost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnorthernmost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20northerly%3B%2Cc0) indicates that it is much less used than 'northernmost'.

Comment: In 60 years of listening I've never noticed "Northmost…" nor "South…" nor "East…" or "Westmost"… and neither does Chrome now.

What did your own research leave unclear?

Comment: There's also 'northermost', which is as frequent in current use as 'northmost'; both are used about half as much as 'northernmost'.

Comment: We also have "most northerly"—in case you feel that the other options are too confining. [Here is an Ngram frequency graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+northmost%2Cthe+northernmost%2Cthe+northermost%2Cthe+most+northerly&year_start=1625&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20northmost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20northernmost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20northermost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20most%20northerly%3B%2Cc0) for "the northmost" vs "the northernmost" vs. "the northermost" vs. "the most northerly" for the period 1625–2008.

Comment: @SvenYargs Wow that's very interesting, cool to see Ngram had a usage frequency for all the four options.